# HTTP Basic Authentication as default in Ruby HTTP

Tags: ruby, http, basic-authentication

Using Ruby 2.2.3 I'm looking for a way to use HTTP Basic Authentication for every request. I know it is possible to define `basic_auth` per request:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("username", "password")
response = http.request(request)
```

How can I "globally" use `basic_auth`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`basic_auth` is an instance method of an `Net::HTTP` object. For convenience you could define a class with the desired `basic_auth` settings baked-in or given as arguments.

Simple example:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

class SimpleHTTP

  def initialize uri, user = "default_user", pass = "default_pass"
    @uri = URI.parse(uri)
    @username = user
    @password = pass
  end

  def request path=nil
    @uri.path = path if path # use path if provided
    http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(@uri.request_uri)
    req.basic_auth(@username, @password)
    http.request(req)
  end


end

# Simple Example
http = SimpleHTTP.new('http://www.yoursite.com/defaultpath')
http.request

# Override default user/pass
http2 = SimpleHTTP.new('http://www.yoursite.com/defaultpath', "myusername", "mypass")
http2.request

# Provide path in request method
http = SimpleHTTP.new('http://www.yoursite.com/')
http.request('/some_path')
```